# id not applying to HTML element for mobile browser

Tags: html, css, mobile, selector

I am facing some problems with css priority on my mobile device. The problem is that css id selector `push-content` is not applying to `body` element. The weird thing is that **it is working on my PC browse**r.

**Code not working for mobile device**:

```css
/* space between content and navigation */
div #push-content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<body id="push-content">
```

**It applied to `body` element after this**:

```
<body style="padding-top: 60px;">
```

I don't feel like this is the only way. Any other way to fix this?

Comment: So you add the id "push-content" to your body element and try to call it with `div#push-content`? That won't work since a `body != div`

Comment: Thank you everybody. I fixed  `#push-content {padding-top:60px;}` and `<body id="push-content"> </body>`. I still see no change on my mobile device. I even tried increasing the padding to 100. Not to mention it works on my browser, confirmed it.

Comment: are you trying to overwrite the inline-styling with the css?

Comment: No, this ( padding-top ) is the only rule in id selector "push-content".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is absolutely terrible. I found the problem. My website is powered by wordpress. I was using the wrong link. Basically, I was hosting the website via XAMP on my local PC for testing purposes. I was using the function `bloginfo('stylesheet_url');` which gave me nightmares. The stylesheet was not being linked on my mobile phone. It was returning `http://localhost:8080/wordpress/` which is the incorrect link for any other device on LAN so I put the IP there and it worked like a charm. I modified it to `http://192.168.1.8:8080/wordpress/` **192.168.1.8** is the IP of source/host computer ( you can find it by opening command console on windows and write "ipconfig" )

**NOTE**: You should use `bloginfo('stylesheet_url');` function. I removed it temporarily because I was testing my website on other devices via LAN with help of XAMP.

Thank you everyone for helping. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

at first you have spaces in between the id = "push-content"

change it to

`id="push-content"`

at second
you have `div #push-content` while you are applying it to a body tag so change that to `body #push-content`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an incorrect selector in your css.

`div #push-content` will select the element with id `push-content` that's a child of a div. So you cannot apply this to your `body`.

Use instead:

```
#push-content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

or even better:

```
.push-content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

using a class here instead of an id will allow you to use it on more than just one element.

Answer (score 1):

your selector is trying to find #push-content inside a div, not a div called #push content. Remove the space between them.

plus - Body is not a div - So you might need body#push-content instead